# auto Submit Form Only when Checkbox is Checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, checkbox

auto Submmiting a form only when a checkbox is checked.

so i've been searching for something like this for awhile and didn't found the proper answer, i've got a chechbox input that has 2 diffrent roles depending on whether it's checked or unchecked. the answers that i've found were something like this:

```
<input onChange="this.form.submit()" ... />
```

or html:

```
<form method="post" id="form2">
        
  <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="switch" onchange="submit()">      
</form>
```

js:

```
function submit () {
$("#switch").change(function() {
        console.log($("#switch").val());
        $('#form2').delay(200).submit();
    });
}
```

as you can see this function will work whether the input gets checked or unchecked and i only want it to work when it gets checked (or only when it gets unchecked).
i can use a php trick to deactivate the onchange event temporarily but i don't think that's a good way to do it.
can anyone help here?
thanks

Comment: `if($("#switch").val()) $('#form2').delay(200).submit();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were halfway there. Attaching the `change` event isn't a bad idea. The problem is that both "checked" and "unchecked" are change events. Hence your function will get executed, no matter if it's checked or unchecked.

The solution is to check whether your checkbox is checked or unchecked inside the function that you run on the change event:

```js
// Make sure the DOM is loaded before executing this JS code
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(ev){

  // Get the checkbox element
  const checkBoxSwitch = document.getElementById('switch');

  // Attach an event handler to the checkox
  checkBoxSwitch.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    
    // In case the checkbox is checked
    if(checkBoxSwitch.checked == true) {
      console.log("The checbkox is checked, submit form");
    }
    // In case the checkbox is not checked
    else {
      console.log("The checkbox is not checked. Do not submit form");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="switch"> Check me to submit!
</form>
```

I've commented the code so you can see how it works.

Comment: i'm using es6 modules so i just imported your code outside the function and deleted 
onchange="submit()" and it worked. thank you bro.